# Writing Excel cell data to Word document is inconsistent

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Below is my Word template, my VBA code, and my output. My problem is that some of the output lines are correct while some are not. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my Word template:

```
[Art Source]
[Day]
[Scripture]
[Title], [Created]
[Creator], [Country], [Life]
[Medium], [Size]
[Location], [City]
```

Here is my VBA code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Create_Art_Doc()
    Dim wApp As Word.Application
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Dim folder As FileDialog
    Dim path As String
    Dim sht As String
    Dim r As Long
    
    r = InputBox("Enter sequence number")
    r = r + 1
        
    Set folder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    folder.AllowMultiSelect = False
    
    If folder.Show = -1 Then
        path = folder.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    
    If path = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\Art + Doc"

    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wApp.Visible = True
    sht = "Details - Year B - 2023-2024"
    
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(Filename:="G:\ArtDoc Master.dotx", ReadOnly:=True)
    
    With wDoc.Application
        .Selection.Find.Text = "[Art_Source]"
        .Selection.Find.Execute
        .Selection = Worksheets(sht).Cells(r, ColAlphaToNum("S"))
        .Selection.EndOf
    
        .Selection.Find.Text = "[Day]"
        .Selection.Find.Execute
        .Selection = Worksheets(sht).Cells(r, ColAlphaToNum("B"))
        .Selection.EndOf
    
        .Selection.Find.Text = "[Scripture]"
        .Selection.Find.Execute
        .Selection = Worksheets(sht).Cells(r, ColAlphaToNum("G"))
        .Selection.EndOf
    
        .Selection.Find.Text = "[Title]"
        .Selection.Find.Execute
        .Selection = Worksheets(sht).Cells(r, ColAlphaToNum("H"))
        .Selection.EndOf
    
        .Selection.Find.Text = "[Created]"
        .Selection.Find.Execute
        .Selection = Worksheets(sht).Cells(r, ColAlphaToNum("I"))
        .Selection.EndOf
    
        .Selection.Find.Text = "[Medium]"
        .Selection.Find.Execute
        .Selection = Worksheets(sht).Cells(r, ColAlphaToNum("J"))
        .Selection.EndOf
    
        .Selection.Find.Text = "[Size]"
        .Selection.Find.Execute
        .Selection = Worksheets(sht).Cells(r, ColAlphaToNum("K"))
        .Selection.EndOf
    
        .Selection.Find.Text = "[Creator]"
        .Selection.Find.Execute
        .Selection = Worksheets(sht).Cells(r, ColAlphaToNum("L"))
        .Selection.EndOf
    
        .Selection.Find.Text = "[Country]"
        .Selection.Find.Execute
        .Selection = Worksheets(sht).Cells(r, ColAlphaToNum("N"))
        .Selection.EndOf
    
        .Selection.Find.Text = "[Life]"
        .Selection.Find.Execute
        .Selection = Worksheets(sht).Cells(r, ColAlphaToNum("M"))
        .Selection.EndOf
    
        .Selection.Find.Text = "[Location]"
        .Selection.Find.Execute
        .Selection = Worksheets(sht).Cells(r, ColAlphaToNum("P"))
        .Selection.EndOf
    
        .Selection.Find.Text = "[City]"
        .Selection.Find.Execute
        .Selection = Worksheets(sht).Cells(r, ColAlphaToNum("Q"))
        .Selection.EndOf
    End With
    
    wDoc.SaveAs2 Filename:=path, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument
    
    ' Close the Word document and the Word application
    wDoc.Close
    wApp.Quit
    ' Clean up
    Set wDoc = Nothing
    Set wApp = Nothing
        
    MsgBox "Art + Doc written to: " & path
End Sub

Function ColAlphaToNum(c As String)
    ColAlphaToNum = InStr("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", c)
End Function
```

And here is my output:

```
https://stregischurch.com/confirmation[Art Source]
Third Sunday of Advent
Isaiah 61:1-4, 8-11
The Dove of the Holy Spirit, 1666 
[Creator], [Country], [Life]
Stained glass, naGian Lorenzo BerniniItalian1598 - 1680
Throne of St. Peter, St. Peter's Basilica, The Vatican
```

Errors in it:

- `[Art Source]` at end of first line
- `[Creator]` etc. on 5th line
- Artist's name, nationality, and life on 6th line, which should have filled the 5th line

Note: 'na' on the sixth line is correct

Comment: Create a mail merge document in Word and use your Excel file as data source. You will not need VBA.

Comment: Please include sample data from your excel file in OP. btw, you don't need UDF `ColAlphaToNum`. Both `Cells(1, 1)` and `Cells(1, "A")` work well.

Comment: You are searching for `[Art_Source]` but the template is `[Art Source]`

Answer (score 0):

There were some slight problems with the selecting of a document content.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Create_Art_Doc()
    Dim wApp As Word.Application
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Dim folder As FileDialog
    Dim path As String
    Dim sht As String
    Dim r As Long

    r = InputBox("Enter sequence number")
    r = r + 1
        
    Set folder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    folder.AllowMultiSelect = False
    
    If folder.Show = -1 Then
        path = folder.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    
    If path = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\Art + Doc"


    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wApp.Visible = True
    
    sht = "Details - Year B - 2023-2024"
    
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(Filename:="G:\ArtDoc Master.dotx", ReadOnly:=True)
    wDoc.Select
    With wApp.Selection.Find
        .Text = "[Art Source]"
        
        .Execute replacewith:=Worksheets(sht).Cells(r, "S")
        '.Selection.EndOf
     wDoc.Select
        
        .Text = "[Day]"
        .Execute replacewith:=Worksheets(sht).Cells(r, "B")
        '.Selection.EndOf
     wDoc.Select
    
        .Text = "[Scripture]"
        .Execute replacewith:=Worksheets(sht).Cells(r, "G")
'        .Selection.EndOf
    wDoc.Select
    
        .Text = "[Title]"
        .Execute replacewith:=Worksheets(sht).Cells(r, "H")
        '.Selection.EndOf
    wDoc.Select
    
        .Text = "[Created]"
        .Execute replacewith:=Worksheets(sht).Cells(r, "I")
        '.Selection.EndOf
    wDoc.Select
    
        .Text = "[Medium]"
        .Execute replacewith:=Worksheets(sht).Cells(r, "J")
        '.Selection.EndOf
    wDoc.Select
    
        .Text = "[Size]"
        .Execute replacewith:=Worksheets(sht).Cells(r, "K")
        '.Selection.EndOf
    wDoc.Select
    
        .Text = "[Creator]"
        .Execute replacewith:=Worksheets(sht).Cells(r, "L")
        '.Selection.EndOf
    wDoc.Select
    
        .Text = "[Country]"
        .Execute replacewith:=Worksheets(sht).Cells(r, "N")
        '.Selection.EndOf
    wDoc.Select
    
        .Text = "[Life]"
        .Execute replacewith:=Worksheets(sht).Cells(r, "M")
        '.Selection.EndOf
    wDoc.Select
    
        .Text = "[Location]"
        .Execute replacewith:=Worksheets(sht).Cells(r, "P")
        '.Selection.EndOf
    wDoc.Select
    
        .Text = "[City]"
        .Execute replacewith:=Worksheets(sht).Cells(r, "Q")
        '.Selection.EndOf

    End With
    
    wDoc.SaveAs2 Filename:=path, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument
    
    ' Close the Word document and the Word application
    wDoc.Close
    wApp.Quit
    ' Clean up
    Set wDoc = Nothing
    Set wApp = Nothing
        
    MsgBox "Art + Doc written to: " & path
End Sub

Function ColAlphaToNum(c As String)
    ColAlphaToNum = InStr("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", c)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, each one of you!  Tips, corrections, etc.  It works the way I desire now.  Again, Thanks!